# getting error `spatstat::density` function related to "iterMax"

Tags: r, iteration, spatstat

Help with error "No of time iterations exceeds iterMax; increase dtt or increase iterMax" for `density` function in R

How do I increase the iterMax?

I am using the library spatstat.

this is my script:

d660 <- density(unmark(control23_network.ppp), 660)

My Point pattern on linear network has:

1969 points
Linear network with 20126 vertices and 21363 lines
Enclosing window: rectangle = [-87.63141, -87.55547] x [41.75817, 41.83858] units

[image]

An example of it working is in the spatstat library with sample dataset:

data(chicago)

chicago

d60 <- density(unmark(chicago), 60)

plot(d60)

d60

This sample dataset has:

Point pattern on linear network
116 points
Multitype, with possible types: assault, burglary, cartheft, damage, robbery, theft, trespass 
Linear network with 338 vertices and 503 lines
Enclosing window: rectangle = [0.3894, 1281.9863] x [153.1035, 1276.5602] feet

Comment: Two things to try: First would be to post a [MCVE]. Second, less desirable for the purposes of increasing the knowledge in SO, would be to try adding iterMax in that call to `spatstat::density.lpp`. (Incorrectly capitalizing function names in R has the undesirable side-effect of misleading newbies.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a question about `spatstat::density.lpp`, the method for `density` for point patterns on a linear network (class `lpp`).

The chosen bandwidth `sigma` is far too large. The enclosing rectangle is about 0.1 units wide, while the bandwidth is `sigma=660` units. This would require a prohibitively large number of iterations of the algorithm, so it refuses.

A reasonable value of bandwidth `sigma` in this example would be between 0.001 and 0.05 units.

Answer (score 1):

Your smoothing bandwidth `sigma` appears to be huge (660 units) compared to the scale of the network (the enclosing rectangle has approximate side lengths 0.1 units). Did you try with something like `sigma = 0.001` or similar? A big value of `sigma` is doomed to give problems. The help says:

> Computational time is short, but increases quadratically with sigma.

It may be that this is not the root problem, but at least it is worth trying before doing a lot of other things.

Finally, what is your version of R and spatstat? The code for `density.lpp` has changed a lot recently.